# Netsuite - Scheduler not running for some intervals

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

I have a Map/Reduce script running in every 15 minutes. While I check the schedule status, it seems few times the execution skips. I have set the priority to "High", Concurrency limit to "2". Please see the screenshot for reference. I am not getting why this skips for few cases. Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

From the above example, the script skips to execute on 3/16/2021 5:01.42 pm

Answer (score 0):

You can try listing all your scheduled and map/reduce scripts. It is likely that some other scheduled or map/reduce script was running at that time. Netsuite will not interrupt a running task so if something else was running through the next slot Netsuite won't have run it.

The other thing I've seen is scripts scheduled for near midnight California time are often skipped or terminated. I haven't looked at this lately so they may have fixed this but if that time is midnight California then that's likely the reason.

Comment: No, there is no other script running at that time.

Comment: what time zone are you in? See my edit on that.

Comment: thanks for your responses. The script runs in PST. Unfortunately, yesterday I can see 5 such occurrences from 2am to 12 pm.

Comment: What about map reduce scripts?

Comment: Actually, its a Map/Reduce script. Still the issue persists. So raised this to NS support.